bash: conditional statement causes "unexpected end of file" on macOS
When I source the following simple script in a bash shell on macOS (Sonoma 14.4.1), I get
"syntax error: unexpected end of file".
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello"
echo "$SHELL"
echo "$BASH_VERSION"
/bin/bash --version

if [[ -n "foobar" ]]; then
  echo "Ok"
fi

echo "Bye"

If I knock out the if-statement (lines 7-9), it behaves as expected.  On Linux (CentOS 7), it (with the if-statement) produces the expected output with "Ok".
I'm using Unix line endings (LF).
macOS result:
$ source bash-if-trouble.sh 
Hello
/bin/bash
3.2.57(1)-release
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin23)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
-bash: bash-if-trouble.sh: line 12: syntax error: unexpected end of file

source ./bash-if-trouble.sh produces a similar result.
CentOS7 result, which is also expected on macOS (modulo the version details, of course):
$ source bash-if-trouble.sh 
Hello
/bin/bash
4.2.46(2)-release
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Ok
Bye

Per @Philippe's suggestion:
$ od -a bash-if-trouble.sh 
0000000    #   !   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h  nl   e   c   h   o
0000020   sp   "   H   e   l   l   o   "  nl   e   c   h   o  sp   "   $
0000040    S   H   E   L   L   "  nl   e   c   h   o  sp   "   $   B   A
0000060    S   H   _   V   E   R   S   I   O   N   "  nl   /   b   i   n
0000100    /   b   a   s   h  sp   -   -   v   e   r   s   i   o   n  nl
0000120   nl   i   f  sp   [   [  sp   -   n  sp   "   f   o   o   b   a
0000140    r   "  sp   ]   ]   ;  sp   t   h   e   n  nl  sp  sp   e   c
0000160    h   o  sp   "   O   k   "  nl   f   i  nl  nl   e   c   h   o
0000200   sp   "   B   y   e   "  nl                                    
0000207


Works for me in the crufty bash 3.2 MacOS ships with, in bash 5.2, and even in zsh.

Can you post the result of the command od -a your-script ?

I can reproduce this if the fi line ends with a carriage return. Fix the script with dos2unix

I'm petty sure there are no stray CR characters in the script.  1) I authored the script on the same macOS system.  2) grep ^M bash-if-trouble.sh produces no output.  3) My editor indicates LF line endings.

What does /bin/bash --version print?

@CurtisG — your comments about the output of od -a bash-if-trouble.sh would be best presented in the question — you'd be able to format the information for readability.

Can you try source ./bash-if-trouble.sh ?

Please add echo "$BASH_VERSION" to your script and then add that output to your question so we can see which bash version you're running when you source the script. The shebang at the top, #!/bin/bash will be ignored when sourcing it btw, the code will run under whichever shell you're running when you source the file. Also, echo "$SHELL" just tells us your default shell, it doesn't tell us which shell is currently running.

Thanks to Philippe, John Bollinger, Jonathan Leffler, and Ed Morton for suggestions.  I've updated the question body accordingly.

bash --version has no reason to be included, and likewise $SHELL (which tells you which shell is configured as default for your user account, but has nothing to do with which one is actively running). $BASH_VERSION is the only authoritative way (other than its array equivalent) to tell which version of bash is currently running; bash --version just tells you which version is first in the PATH, which is a separate and unrelated thing.

Anyhow -- a good place to start might be to try to build a reproducer in an online sandbox. If you can make the same problem happen in https://ideone.com/, that means you've isolated the necessary elements enough that we're not needing to guess about things on your machine (that you may not personally know about yourself).

Another thing you might do, though, is set PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+'; set -x before the source command, and check whether the filename in the xtrace output matches the name of the file you dumped.

Regarding the concern about which instance of bash is being used, I'll note that type -a bash and which -a bash indicate that there is only one instance found, /bin/bash.

@CharlesDuffy, the script produces the expected output using bash on ideone.com.  That output indicates GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).  I don't see any way to control the version of bash used there.

I should have suggested https://repl.it/; since that can use any package available in Nix, one can select a specific bash version there (including requesting that completely arbitrary builds be constructed from source).

In the absence of a bash bug, it looks like something is causing the then or fi commands to be ignored.  Perhaps there is a rogue alias that is trumping the shell built-in?  What do you get with just
alias

to see all of the aliases?

Doh!  That is the problem.  alias fi='finger -i'.  Once I eliminate that alias, the script works as expected.
